# How can I make sure ASDF loads a dynamic foreign library every time my system is loaded?

Tags: common-lisp, asdf

I am looking for the idiomatic way to set up my project whether by an option in the .asd file or other way so that a dynamic foreign library that I depend on is loaded automatically using cffi.

Here is what I'm trying:
in a file called armadillo.lisp I have

```
    ;;; Load the Armadillo Libraries
(push "/users/mcheema/src/c++/lisp-armadillo/" cffi:*FOREIGN-LIBRARY-DIRECTORIES*)
(cffi:define-foreign-library lisp-armadillo-lib
  (t "lisp-armadillo.dylib"))
(cffi:load-foreign-library 'lisp-armadillo-lib)
```

when I first start up slime I will type

```
(ql:register-local-projects)
(asdf:load-system :cl-armadillo)
```

This throws an error:

```
CL-USER> (asdf:load-system :cl-armadillo)
;Compiling "/Users/mcheema/src/lisp/cl-armadillo/src/armadillo.lisp"...;
Evaluation aborted on #<CFFI::FOREIGN-LIBRARY-UNDEFINED-ERROR #x3020017A461D>.
```

If I then Just cut and paste the same cffi code fragment above into my slime REPL I get:

```
CL-USER> (push "/users/mcheema/src/c++/lisp-armadillo/" cffi:*FOREIGN-LIBRARY-DIRECTORIES*)
(cffi:define-foreign-library lisp-armadillo-lib
  (t "lisp-armadillo.dylib"))
(cffi:load-foreign-library 'lisp-armadillo-lib)


#<FOREIGN-LIBRARY LISP-ARMADILLO-LIB "lisp-armadillo.dylib">
```

EDIT: To answer Dirk's comment. Currently both specials.lisp and io.lisp are empty files save a defpackage and one form for the overall project version number.

```
(in-package :cl-user)
(defpackage cl-armadillo-asdf
  (:use  :cl :asdf))
(in-package :cl-armadillo-asdf)
(defsystem cl-armadillo
  :author  "Munawar Cheema"
  :license "LLGPL"
  :version "0.0.1"
  :depends-on (:uiop :cffi)
  :components (
               (module "src"
                       :components
                       ((:file "armadillo" :depends-on ("io"))
                        (:file "io" :depends-on ("specials"))
                        (:file "specials"))))
  :description "Create a simple interface to the armadillo library"
  :long-description "Create a simple interface to the armadillo library"
;  :in-order-to ((test-op (load-op cl-armadillo-test))) ; see fukamachi/cl-project.asd
  )
```

I'll include armadillo.lisp to point of failure as well

```
(in-package :cl-user)
(defpackage cl-armadillo
  (:use
   #:cl
   #:uiop
   #:cffi
   #:cl-armadillo.specials
   #:cl-armadillo.io)
  (:nicknames :arm)
  (:export matrix-destroy
           matref
           make-matrix-ones
           make-matrix-randu
           make-matrix-zeros
           make-matrix-eye))

(in-package :cl-armadillo)

;;; Load the Armadillo Libraries
(push "/users/mcheema/src/c++/lisp-armadillo/" cffi:*FOREIGN-LIBRARY-DIRECTORIES*)
(cffi:define-foreign-library lisp-armadillo-lib
  (t "lisp-armadillo.dylib"))
(cffi:load-foreign-library 'lisp-armadillo-lib)
```

Comment: Usually libraries just have a file that loads the foreign library near the top of the load order (after package definition).

Comment: Maybe it would help, if you'd show us the `.asd` file. According to the output you give, you get a compilation error in `cl-armadillo/src/armadillo.lisp`, but you said, that the code to load the library lives in `cl-armadillo.lisp`. It is unclear to me, what gets (or should be) loaded when.

Comment: @Dirk the system is called cl-armadillo and will comprise many packages but currently just getting a skeleton going with the code in armadillo.lisp. I modified the question to show the system file

Comment: Could you include a backtrace to see where that `FOREIGN-LIBRARY-UNDEFINED-ERROR` is signaled?

Comment: Also: Please try `(cffi:load-foreign-library "lisp-armadillo.dylib")` (thus bypassing the `define-foreign-library`)

Comment: @DanielJour thanks I'll try it out; I was looking to see if my approach was wrong but it sounds like I'm doing the right sort of thing. Just need to debug this.

Comment: It appears that the problem has something to do with where the symbol for the library lisp-armadillo-lib is interned.  The symbol it tries to use is cl-armadillo::lisp-armadillo-lib but what seems to work is cl-user::lisp-armadillo-lib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some trial and error I figured out how to make sure my code works with asdf:load-system everytime.  The key was to wrap the definition of the library and update of cffi:*foreign-library-directories in an eval-when form:

```
(eval-when
    (:compile-toplevel :load-toplevel :execute)
  (pushnew #P"/users/mcheema/src/c++/lisp-armadillo/" cffi:*FOREIGN-LIBRARY-DIRECTORIES*)
  (cffi:define-foreign-library lisp-armadillo-lib
    (t "lisp-armadillo.dylib"))
  (cffi:load-foreign-library 'lisp-armadillo-lib))
```

Code Edited to reflect pushnew suggestion in comments

Comment: You should use `PUSHNEW` instead of only checking the `CAR` like that. The directory might not be the first element in the list.